# Reaching the main word from the suffix list

Tags: c#, morphological-analysis

I have a word like "itibarsızlaştırmak".

The stem is "itibar" and the suffix list is  "a, ak, ar, ı, laş, m, sız, i".

***The suffix list is missing. "ma, tır, ız, i, ı, a, m, sı, mak, tı, sız, ak, ar, laş" is the right one.***

How can i to reach "itibarsızlaştırmak" with suffix list in which order?

For Example : itibar + suffixList[6] -> itibarsız

itibar + suffixList[6] + suffixList[5] -> itibarsızlaş

Words and suffix list changes all time. So I need a algorithm for it. I tried merge suffix one by one with stem and comparision but it is not work for all list.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a stem word and a list of suffixes you want to join? If so, `string.Join( "", suffixes );`

Comment: Every possible suffix is in list even if it is not use. I need to choose right ones with right order.

Comment: Make a second list of the suffix indices and `string.Join( "", indices.Select( i => suffixes[ i ] ) )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Dictionary with assigned suffixes to words is a way of achieving this.

This code does however needs to be tweaked to discern suffixes not in the list and suffixes that are similar (like 'a' and 'ak' in your example).

#### UPDATE

Fixed the search pattern for the suffixes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var words = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        words.Add("itibar", new List<string>(){"ma", "tır", "ız", "i", "ı", "a", "m", "sı", "mak", "tı", "sız", "ak", "ar", "laş"}.OrderBy(e => e.Length).ToList());
        
        var word = "itibarsızlaştırmak";
        
        var wordUsed = words.FirstOrDefault(e => word.Contains(e.Key));
        
        var suffixesUsedInOrder = new List<string>();
        var charsToSearch = "";
        
        foreach (var character in word.Substring(wordUsed.Key.Length))
        {
            var a = character.ToString();
            if (charsToSearch.Length > 0) 
            {
                a = charsToSearch + a;  
            }
            
            if (!wordUsed.Value.Any(e => e == a) || wordUsed.Value.Count(e => e.StartsWith(a)) > 1)
            {
                charsToSearch += character.ToString();
            }
            else 
            {
                suffixesUsedInOrder.Add(wordUsed.Value.FirstOrDefault(e => e == a));
                charsToSearch = "";
            }
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", suffixesUsedInOrder));
            
    }
}
```

The result of this code run: `sız,laş,tır,mak`

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir. Sorry the suffix list is missing. "ma, tır, ız, i, ı, a, m, sı, mak, tı, sız, ak, ar, laş" is the right list. When I try this list in your code result is "sı". I think "sı" is fit first but there is no other suffix to complete word. There is multiple possibilities i guess.

Comment: @CircasCreed I updated the code with all the suffixes and changed the search pattern to now give a complete list of suffixes in order.

Comment: Thank you. It is work for almost all of my words.